# Variations in MATLAB plot each time the program is executed

Tags: matlab, digital-communications

Every time I run the program my PLOT in MATLAB gets changed to some extent (some times to larger extent too).

I understood that the channel is random and this might happen due to random distributions used to model the channel. Is there any way to solve this issue, so that every time I get the same values and plot.

Comment: You have to average over a certain number of channel realizations

Comment: I am not sure about how we can answer here. You can stack the plots, to get a cumulative vision of how things change; but I don't know yet why it could be disturbing

Comment: @ Laurent , it is disturbing because some time Bit error rate curve goes below and some time it goes above.

Comment: @ Dsp guy, can you give simple example.

Comment: Are you trying to run models with the same sequence of random numbers so it becomes repeatable? If yes, use $rng()$ to control the seed of the random number generator

Comment: I'm not sure but it sounds like you are plotting a simulation curve over the top of a theoretical curve, if that is true and your simulated curve doesn't track smoothly over the theoretical then it could be that you don't average over enough simulation runs or a bug in the code

Comment: @ engineer, yes it's true. Average over enough simulation means I have to use for loop and repeat the same instruction ( for e.g., to generate channel) multiple ( say 1000) times. Is this correct or is there something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plots are changing i.e. you are changing inputs to the model (be it random input sequence , random channel matrix , random gaussian noise ) .. there are lot of random combinations here.. which will definitely change the plot.. you cannot expect to have same plot everytime when you are dealing with random numbers.. 
You can control with using same seed in random number generator.

- Use the same seed while dealing with random numbers

Quick google search on this gave me this which you can use

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/generate-random-numbers-that-are-repeatable.html

Comment: ,ok understood the method in the link.